# Stop d3dcompiler_47.dll from compiling

Tags: visual-studio, direct3d

I'm currently creating a dll which is going to be injected into a process, it includes the d3d11 lib. Since I cannot map a single dependency, I have to make sure that all the dll's are already mapped. There is just one dll getting in my way (d3dcompiler_47.dll), apparently the function D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain invokes the dll in some kind, if compiling without the function, d3dcompiler is not required. I read quite some stuff on msdn and apparently it has something to do with (runtime) shaders, but is there a way or a command which lets me disable it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a program called "dependency walker" and found what function of d3dcompiler_47.dll was called -> located it in the source code and changed the code so d3dcompiler_47.dll isn't necessary anymore.